# For help about: Brezis Lemma 1.3 Hahn-Banach geometric form

Tags: functional-analysis

Lemma 1.3. Let $C \subset E$ be a nonempty open convex set and let $x_{0} \in E$ with $x_{0} \notin C$. Then there exists $f \in E^{\star}$ such that $f(x)<f\left(x_{0}\right) \quad \forall x \in C .$ In particular, the hyperplane [ $\left.f=f\left(x_{0}\right)\right]$ separates $\left\{x_{0}\right\}$ and $C$.

Proof of Lemma 1.3. ***After a translation we may always assume that $0 \in C$***. We may thus introduce the gauge $p$ of $C$ (see Lemma 1.2). Consider the linear subspace $G=\mathbb{R} x_{0}$ and the linear functional $g: G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by......

```
How should I understand the bolded part of this lemma? Why can we assume that?
```

Answer (score 1):

Emmm，well, I was so stupid, I didn't realize I just had to do the new set $D=C-c_{0}$, where  $c_{0} \in C$

For more detail, let $D=C-c_{0}$, then can easy check that $D$ is also an open convex set, and $0 \in D$. For $x_{0}\in E\backslash C$, let $y_{0}=x_{0}-c_{0}$, so we know $y_{0}\notin D$. Then according to the proof of the lemma 1.3, we know there exists $f\in E^{\star}$ and $f(y)<f(y_{0}), \forall y\in D$. So $\forall x\in C, f(x)=f(y+c_{0})=f(y)+f(c_{0})<f(y_{0})+f(c_{0})=f(y_{0}+c_{0})=f(x_{0})$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you very much!